# JTemplate Error

Tags: jquery, json

I want to use JTemplate on my php page. My template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="TemplateResultsTable">
            {#template MAIN}
            <table  cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
            <th>Seller</th>
            <th>Bid Amount</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
            {#foreach $T.d as CD}
            {#include ROW root=$T.CD}
            {#/for}
            </table>
            {#/template MAIN}
            {#template ROW}
            <tr>
            <td>{$T.Bidder}</td>
            <td>{$T.Bid}</td>
            <td>{$T.BidDate}</td>
            </tr>
            {#/template ROW}
</script>
```

My ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.noConflict();

        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   

        $('#ctl0_Main_BidHistoryPortlet_ctl0').click(function(){
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/index.php/page,Service',
                data: 'action=TestFunction&AuctionId='+$('#ctl0_Main_BidHistoryPortlet_AuctionId').val(),
                success: function(msg)
                {               
                    ApplyTemplate(msg);
                } 
            });

        });

        function ApplyTemplate(msg) 
        {
            $('#Container').setTemplate($("#TemplateResultsTable").html());
            $('#Container').processTemplate(msg);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Json data that come from Service.php is correct. But I get following error:
"cannot read property 'length' of undefined" 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

adding

```
 $.ajax
            ({
               dataType:"json" , ...
```

Comment: When I add dataType:"json" I get following error "cannot read property 'd' of undefined"